# anacondaのインストール先とカレントディレクトリについて

Tags: anaconda

anacondaについてです。

anaconda3をDドライブ内にインストールしました。
スタートメニューにあるanaconda promptを起動すると、
`(base) C￥Users￥ユーザ名>`
と表記されます。

anaconda promptで出ているこの表記とanacondaがインストールされている先は関係ないのでしょうか。
anacondaはDドライブ内にインストールされているが、起動しているディレクトリがCドライブ内という認識で正しいのでしょうか。

教えていただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

表示されている `C￥Users￥ユーザ名>` はあくまで **作業ディレクトリ** であり、インストール先とは異なります。

Answer (score 0):

- anaconda promptで出ているこの表記とanacondaがインストールされている先は関係ないのでしょうか。
- anacondaはDドライブ内にインストールされているが、起動しているディレクトリがCドライブ内という認識で正しいのでしょうか。

いずれも正しいと思われます。
細かく言うと「実行するユーザーのホームディレクトリ」になっているはずです。

「スタートメニューにあるanaconda prompt」を表示して右クリックで「その他」の「ファイルの場所を開く」として、さらに該当のショートカットを右クリックで「プロパティ」表示すると、「作業フォルダー」が`%HOMEPATH%`になっているはずです。

おそらくインストール先のドライブやフォルダーを変更しても(あるいはインストール形態を「すべてのユーザー」としても？)、このショートカットの`%HOMEPATH%`は変えないと思われます。

変更したいならばそれらショートカットのプロパティの「作業フォルダー」を変えれば良いでしょう。

例えばこれらの記事で解説されています。
[Anaconda Prompt の作業フォルダを変更](http://izmmr.blog.jp/archives/10188841.html)
[Anaconda / Python: Change Anaconda Prompt User Path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48304305/9014308)

---

他にjupyter notebook, jupyter labなどはまた別の方法で変えることになるでしょう。

[〔Jupyter notebook初期フォルダ変更〕できない時のチェック点４つ](https://yululy.com/%E3%80%94jupyter-notebook%E5%88%9D%E6%9C%9F%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%80%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%80%95%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF/)
[Jupyter Lab の作業フォルダを変更](http://izmmr.blog.jp/archives/10190643.html)

jupyter lab 3.0.0 以後は設定ファイル名が変わったようです。

[JupyterLab3.0の起動ブラウザを指定する方法](https://qiita.com/matsxxx/items/10c93edab12a93604aab)